# sympy collect undefined functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy, collect

I have an expression in sympy that is a linear combination of an evaluated function, `f`. Schematically

```
expr  = Sum_{m,n} c_{m,n} f(x+a_m,y+a_n)
```

where `c_{m,n}` is a coefficient depending on the variables `x,y`. A very simple example is

```
import sympy as sp

x, y = sp.symbols("x, y")
f = sp.Function("f")(x,y)

expr = 0
for i in range(0,3):
    expr += (x-i)* f.subs({x: x+2*i, y: y+3*i})
```

In my actual code `expr` is the result of a long succession of sums and the function `g` not simplify like here. Is there an efficient way of grouping functions with different argument together, like `collect(expr)` does for polynomials? What I am after is to obtain a structured list:

```
In: someFunction(...)
Out: [..., [c_{m,n}, x+a_m, y+a_n ], ...]
```

in the example above

```
In: someFunction(expr)
Out: [[x, x, y], [x - 1, x + 2, y + 3], [x - 2, x + 4, y + 6]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this does exactly what you want but you can use pattern matching:

```
In [27]: expr                                                                                                                                  
Out[27]: x⋅f(x, y) + (x - 2)⋅f(x + 4, y + 6) + (x - 1)⋅f(x + 2, y + 3)

In [28]: a, b, c = symbols('a, b, c', cls=Wild)                                                                                                

In [29]: pattern = a*f(b, c)                                                                                                                   

In [30]: for term in Add.make_args(expr): 
    ...:     print(term.match(pattern)) 
    ...:                                                                                                                                       
{b_: x, c_: y, a_: x}
{b_: x + 2, c_: y + 3, a_: x - 1}
{b_: x + 4, c_: y + 6, a_: x - 2}
```

Comment: You can get the lists as in your question with `m = term.match(pattern); [m[i] for i in (a,b,c)]`.